# How to fix connection refused on a socket io server in an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, socket.io, virtual-machine

I have this simple Socket IO server and I'm trying to run a Ubuntu VM on Azure.

```
import express from "express";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { createServer } from "http";
import cors from "cors";

//Seting up app
const app = express();
const serverHttp = createServer(app);
//CORS seems fine
app.use(cors());
const io = new Server(serverHttp, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});
//Creating server
serverHttp.listen(3002, () => {
  console.log('listening on 3002');
});

//Logging when someone connects
io.on('connection', () => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Everything works fine on localhost, I can connect without issues, however, I can't make this work for the love of God in a simple Azure Ubuntu VM. I get a connection refused error. The port is open, I can reach it via REST but not through socket io. Here's a screenshot for the network configuration:

[Network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XH3D.png)

Ports 3000-3002 are open. REST works, but no socket io. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi @Vovozona, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1):

•   I would suggest you to please check whether your **Ubuntu VM have updates installed for ‘udev’**. As **‘udev’ incorrectly saves the network interfaces**, due to which such issues are encountered. Also, to **update the ‘udev’ package on a VM, execute the following commands** on your VM: -

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install udev
```

•   Also, please check the below related **network files on your Ubuntu VM for any misconfigurations**: -

**Network card configuration, Configuration files for default gateway, Static routes – ‘/etc/network/interfaces’**

**Hostname configuration – ‘/etc/hostname’**

**DNS configuration files - ‘/etc/nsswitch.conf’**

**Firewall rules – ‘/etc/ufw/ufw.conf’`**

•   Finally, would recommend you **establish a telnet session from your local machine to try and reach the Azure ubuntu VM**. For this purpose, **telnet client should be installed and enabled in your local system from which you are accessing the Azure ubuntu VM** as below: -

```
 telnet yourhostnameorip 3001
```

Like the above, **telnet every possible port that is necessary for connection. This will tell you which ports are blocked, and which ports need to be opened in the network security group for connection to be successful through socket IO**.

For more information, kindly refer the below links for more information: -

**https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/socketio-not-working-in-live-server-ubuntu**

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/cannot-connect-linux-network**